# Cannot use Task to make TimelineEntry inside getTimeline

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, task, widgetkit

I am making widgets for WatchOS and i am struggling with the **getTimeline** and **getSnapshot** functions for **TimelineProvider**

The error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

This is the code inside **getTimeline**

```
Task {
    let price = try? await service.fetchPrices()
    if let priceSingle = price?.current {
       let entry = Entry(date: Date(), price: priceSingle, priceItems: price?.today!, isPlaceholder: false)
       let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: TimelineReloadPolicy.after(Date().addingTimeInterval(60*30)))
       completion(timeline)
    } else {
         let entry = Entry.placeholder
         let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 2)))
         completion(timeline)   
        }
    }
```

The error happend when i added this line

```
let entry = Entry(date: Date(), price: priceSingle, priceItems: price?.today!, isPlaceholder: false)
```

Works fine when creating widgets for iOS.
Maybe its a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `price?.today!` you cannot force wrapped optional like this, you need to write it like this `(price?.today)!`.

**But this will crash your app if it's nil.** So better to optionally wrapped using the [`nil-coalescing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/__(_:_:)-8buau) operator.

```
price?.today ?? [] //If it is an array
price?.today ?? "" //If it is a string
```

You haven't added `Entry` so I'm not sure what is the type of `today`property but you can pass some default value after the `??` like above.